# How to satisfy PEP8 and also set logging levels before importing

Tags: python

The entry point to my application is a `handler.py` file. I am using an aws lambda.

In this file, I import packages. However, some of these packages (aws stuff like botocore) log dozens to a hundred of lines, just on import. I want to do something like:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("culprit_aws_loggers").setlevel(logging.CRITICAL)

import the rest of my stuff.
```

This breaks PEP8 though. What's the accepted way to set log levels in the entry point of an app?

Comment: How exactly does it break PEP8, what message/error do you get?

Comment: PEP-8 is a set of conventions. Correctness beats convention. If you need to configure the logger before other `import` statements, so be it. (Whether a module should produce side effects like logging on import is a topic for a different discussion.)

Comment: So the question is really, how do I make whatever linter I am using stop complaining about "out of order" imports?

Comment: What linter are you using and what rule does it say this violates? Have you considered giving it a directive to ignore the style violation here? The format is normally a comment like `# lintername:ignore=rule_code`